# Como trazer uma imagem de um site na requisição da API Node?

Tags: node.js, api, http, express.js

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e queria que após dar uma requisição, que a API trouxesse uma imagem desse [site](https://http.cat/) como resposta. Por exemplo, ao dar o erro 404, gostaria que trouxesse [isso](https://http.cat/404).

Como posso fazer?

Atualmente tenho um método desse:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Não há nada aqui :c');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            mensagem: error.message
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada na documentação do [objeto de resposta](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#res) do *ExpressJS*? Existe um método próprio para envio de arquivos que pode servir para o que você está precisando.

Comment: @GustavoSampaio ja olhei sim cara, mas por ser novo nesse mundo, não consegui descobrir uma resposta certa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única forma que achei foi essa:

```
app.use((error, req, res, next) => { 
    res.status(error.status || 500); 
    res.send(`<img src="http://http.cat/${error.status || 500}" />`); 
});
```

Ou seja, ele manda como resposta um elemento `<img>`, tendo o atributo `src` com o link da imagem do site, de acordo com o código de erro.

Se você quiser, você pode adicionar o `style` ao elemento, deixando a imagem ocupar a tela inteira:

```
res.send(`<img src="http://http.cat/${error.status || 500}" style="width:100%;" />`);
```

**O `res.sendFile` não seria o adequado para essa ocasião**

O `res.sendFile` só funciona para enviar arquivos que estão no mesmo servidor. E desse modo, não teria como adicionar o link da imagem como caminho de arquivo, pois, retornaria um erro de "arquivo não existente".

Espero ter ajudado!